# If $F=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}F=0$ Then the tangent fails to exist .

Tags: calculus, algebraic-geometry

Let $F(x,y)=0$ and $F$ is polynomials, and $F=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}F=0$.

Why does the tangent fails to exist ?

Comment: Let $F(x,y)=x^3-y^3$. Then at $(0,0)$ both $F$ and its partial derivatives are zero, yet the tangent to $F(x,y)=0$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

if $F_x= F_y= 0$ then the tangent vector is the 0 vector.  That is not the same as saying the derivative does not exist.  (And the fact that F= 0 at that point is not relevant.)